# Existe alguna propuesta para intentar solucionar estos numeros

Tags: discusión

El caso es que ultimamente me llama mucho la atencion, el ver muchas preguntas contestadas y que el usuario no acepta ninguna respuesta (con lo perjudicial que es eso y sobre todo en estos momentos) alguno numeros:

cogidos de una pagina al azar:

> Preguntas totales : 50
>
> Preguntas con alguna respuesta (1 o mas) que no
> han sido aceptadas : 19 aprox.
>
> Preguntas sin respuesta : 18 aprox

Con lo que se saca que solo `13 preguntas de 50` han sido aceptadas, obviamente dependera de la pagina que se vea, pero lo he calculado y los numeros son muy similares (rapidamente).

Lo cual bajo mi punto de vista son unas cifras un poco desconcertantes, **quizas si no existe alguna medida para intentar frenar eso**, quiero decir, el que la gente nueva o no tan nueva, no se preocupe en adaptarse a las "normas" de la comunidad y seguir haciendo pregunta sin aceptarlas (*total para que aceptar si me las responden igual*). Se podria usar este hilo para buscar alguna solucion o alguna forma de proceder en estos caso, de una manera unificadas en el que tras llegar a un concenso todos los interesado podamos intentar frenar esto.

P.D: Aunque quizas son imaginaciones mias y esto no es tan grave a como yo lo percibo.

**Update:**

Muchas son las cosas malas de esta forma comportamientos, pero por ejemplo aplicado a usuarios nuevos.

Considero que es bueno que la gente haga sus pregunta e inquitudes, pero igual de importante es conservar a los usuarios nuevo que estan dispuesta a responder a esas preguntas no solo interesa tener usuarios que solo pregunta, dicho esto. Creo que este comportamiento puede afectar en gran medida a dichos usuarios (porque si vienes de SO pues tampoco te preocupa mucho la rep. porque sabes como funciona el sito) pero si como dije eres nuevo y quieres contribuir con tus conocimientos y nadie hace upvote a tus preguntas ect. (suponiendo que estas sean correctas) es posible que ese usuario no se sienta motivado ha seguir contestando preguntas despues de experimentar varias veces comportamientos similares.

Con lo que es posible que ganemos usuarios que pregunten y/o no upvote ect, pero perdamos gente dispuesta a ayudar.

Dicho lo cual se me ocurre que quizas tambien se podria tener encuenta las preguntas de los usuarios nuevos (o tener mas encuenta) para intentar votarlas en la medida de lo posible aunque exista otra pregunta mejor, no quiero decir votar solo la menos buena, sino votar tambien la menos buena si esta es de un usuario nuevo y por ejemplo no tiene ningun.

Comment: Asociados: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262672/1065197 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275594/1065197

Comment: Un duplicado y estan en ingles, lo siento pero no me parece que por estar en ingles cuenten como diplicado @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Vale no habia visto la de arriba @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: El duplicado está en español y en este mismo sitio. No se puede votar como duplicado con una pregunta que no es del sitio. Los otros son asociados, es decir, similares a esta pregunta, pero en otros sitios de la red. Recomiendo un poco más de cautela y revisar la pregunta que se marca como duplicado.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Aunque el "duplicado" no es lo que yo queria transmitir. Yo pretendia crear un concenso de la gente que quiera solucionar este problema el hacer algo ya sea mediante comentarios ect. pero de una forma mas unificada, no pretendo que se cree un algoritmo ect. para tratar este problema, si no una manera de hacer entender a los "nuevo" como funciona el sito y motivarlos a interactuar con el.

Comment: El resumen es: no puedes. Sobretodo si hay un usuario que solo postea su pregunta y nunca más vuelve a participar en el sitio. No se puede contactar a estos usuarios. Su correo es información personal que ni siquiera los moderadores accedemos. Referirse a: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/822/227 (de alguna manera u otra, este tema ya se ha cubierto en el pasado).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza quien asume que todos los usuarios que no aceptan no vuelven al sitio he visto varios que siguen preguntado y actuando de la misma manera, y quizas nunca se les ha dicho nada sobre su forma de actuar.

Comment: No lo asumo. Son los hechos. Me ha pasado desde el sitio en inglés. Aquí algunos usuarios que puedes revisar su actividad y evaluar el por qué de estas "actitudes": [1](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/195) [2](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/14571), [3](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/14637), [4](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/3205). Puedes revisar más usuarios con [este SEDE básico](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/630630/usuarios-soes-con-preguntas-sin-respuestas) (inclusive refinarlo para más detalles).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza que bastantes tengan esa actitud no te lo voy a discutir, pero aun asi no se esta tratando el problema, que pasa con el resto de usuarios que no entran dentro de ese perfil, los que existen ahora mismo y los que vendran en un futuro, pero claro si desde la moderacion ect del sitio, no quieren poner solucion o por lo menos intentarlo, y se cierran propuestas para atacar el problema yo no puedo hacer nada, mas que seguir intentado que este comportamiento no se extienda y quizas en el intento alguno recapacite.

Comment: Bueno, puedes intentarlo. Pero lo más probable es que resulte en un efecto contrario.

Comment: ¿Puede intentarlo? Cuando lo intenta le cierras la pregunta. Esa otra pregunta trata sobre una propuesta concreta para solucionar el problema. Mientras que esta pregunta de Angel Angel trata sobre todas las otras propuestas.

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: [¿Cómo funciona la estadística “porcentaje de preguntas contestadas” en Area 51?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/985/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-estad%C3%ADstica-porcentaje-de-preguntas-contestadas-en-area-51)

Comment: Dejo aquí una propuesta: [PROPUESTA: Usemos el botón y pestaña Sin Responder](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457/propuesta-usemos-el-bot%C3%B3n-y-pesta%C3%B1a-sin-responder)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que para *mejorar* estos números también deberíamos revisar tanto preguntas como respuestas que *después de un tiempo* usuarios nuevos han dejado de hacer seguimiento y se han convertido en contenido *sin valor*; creo que al empezar a votar negativamente y/o reportarlas (flag) como baja calidad *(o según la pregunta/respuesta lo requiera)* la misma comunidad estaría alentando a que aquellas preguntas/respuestas sean eliminadas del sitio.

---

Personalmente he visto algunas preguntas y respuestas que *siendo de usuarios nuevos* aún no conocen cómo elaborar las preguntas y respuestas según las normas del sitio.

En casos que considero que *aún siendo usuarios nuevos*, he evitado votar en contra o reportarlas para darle mas tiempo a los usuarios a que mejoren sus aportes.

Sin embargo, con el paso del tiempo, esas preguntas ni son respondidas ni generan valor al sitio.

---

Por otro lado, si hay preguntas y/o respuestas que aún no han sido aceptadas y se justifican para merecer votos positivos<sup>1</sup>, deberían concederse dichos votos *(y/o las acciones que requieran)*.

<sup>1</sup> votos positivos por **utilidad**, tal como dice el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up):

> **¿Cuándo debería dar un voto positivo?**
>
> Cuando te encuentras una pregunta, respuesta o comentario que piensas
>   que es útil, ¡Vota positivo!