# PROPUESTA: Usemos el botón y pestaña Sin Responder

Tags: discusión

Lo publico como nueva pregunta pues [Existe alguna propuesta para intentar solucionar estos numeros](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1435/)  está cerrada

Botones mostrados en todos las páginas
[image: Barra de botones]

Pestañas mostradas al visitar cualquier etiqueta:

[image: Barra de pestañas]

Comment: piensa que sin responder no es que no tenga respuestas si no que muestra las que no tienen respuesta aceptada. Y en muchos casos el que formula la pregunta, coge su solucion y se las pira sin aceptar. Pero si, es util hacer repasos a esa seccion. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b sin responder muestra las que no tienen respuesta aceptada... y además la respuesta tiene puntuación igual a 0. Por tanto, siempre va bien darle una ojeada por si las respuestas pueden merecer un voto positivo.

Answer (score 4):

Gran propuesta. Me apunto.

Y en caso de que tengas especial interés en las preguntas con ninguna respuesta , que como ha explicado lois6b no es exáctamente lo que hace ese botón, puedes hacerlo [poniendo `answers:0` en la búsqueda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0).

Y si quisieses ver preguntas sin respuestas y sin votos... No se como hacerlo pero puedes hacer algo muy parecido restringiendo a puntuación total 0 (es posible que hayan tenido votos positivos iguales a los negativos).
[answers:0 score:0..0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0%20%20score%3A0..0)

Comment: Pues tienes razón. Hay que ver la gran cantidad de preguntas que contienen la palabra and.

Comment: Yo ya lo llevo haciendo desde hace tiempo...
...y no se me ocurre ninguna respuesta válida...